# Paste email body to insertion point of word document

Tags: vba, email, outlook, ms-word

I'm attempting to create a macro that opens a new word document, inserts 2 tables, and then pastes the content of a current email below the tables. I've managed this using .InsertAfter but lose the format of the email, images etc. When i use copy and paste my code over rights the tables. Here's my code. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. My coding is largely based on trial and error.

```
Public Sub EmailtoWord()

Dim objWordApp As Word.Application
Dim objWordDocument As Word.Document
Dim objWordRange As Word.Range

Dim headerTables As Word.Table
Dim headerIndex As Long
Dim headerRange As Word.Range

Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objMail As Object

Dim oPara As Paragraph 'Remove empty lines

Set objWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objWordDocument = objWordApp.Documents.Add
objWordDocument.Activate
Set objWordRange = objWordDocument.Range(0, 0)
objWordApp.Visible = True
objWordDocument.ActiveWindow.Visible = True

For headerIndex = 1 To 2
Set headerRange = ActiveDocument.Range(ActiveDocument.Content.End - 1, ActiveDocument.Content.End)
Set headerTable = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=headerRange, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=4)
ActiveDocument.Content.InsertParagraphAfter

ActiveDocument.Tables(headerIndex).Borders.Enable = True
Next

Set headerRange = headerTable.Range
With headerRange
.Collapse 0
.Move Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
.Select
End With
 
Set objOutlook = Outlook.Application

    Select Case TypeName(objOutlook.ActiveWindow)
  
    Case "Inspector"    ' get open item
        Set objMail = objOutlook.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select
    
   objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Copy
   objWordDocument.Range.Collapse Direction:=WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart
   objWordDocument.Range.Paste
          
  '  With ActiveDocument.Range
  ' .InsertAfter objMail.Body
  '  End With
  
For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
   If Len(oPara.Range.Text) = 1 Then
      oPara.Range.Delete
   End If
Next

End Sub
Sub test()
    Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    With MyRange.Find
        .Text = "Insert"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchWildcards = False
        bFound = .Execute
    End With
    If bFound Then
        Set ChartObj = wb1.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
        ChartObj.Chart.ChartArea.Copy
        MyRange.Words.Last.Paste
    End If
End Sub
```

WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart doesn't appear to work

Comment: Is this code in Outlook?  If it is then you will need to add a reference to the Microsoft Word object model if you want to use word enumerations by name.  Otherwise you will need to use the number value of the enumeration.

Comment: Thank you, yes the code is in Outlook so I'll take a look at that.

Comment: The Word Object Library box is checked

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the following methods like `Paste`:

```
objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Copy
objWordDocument.Range.Collapse Direction:=WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart
objWordDocument.Range.Paste
```

Try using the [Range.PasteAndFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.pasteandformat) or [Range.PasteSpecial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.pastespecial) methods instead to preserve the formatting.

Be aware, when dealing with the Word object model, if you don't know what property or method to use, consider using the VBA macro recorder which allows generating the VBA code for you, see [Create or run a macro](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-or-run-a-macro-c6b99036-905c-49a6-818a-dfb98b7c3c9c) for more information.